# Salesforce Controller Test: getAccounts method not filtering by profile

Tags: apex, unit-test, profile, filters, custom-controller

I have a custom controller that is intended to return a results set to a visualforce page for customized viewing.  It works fine in production.  When building my unit test for this controller, however, I set up a dummy sales rep User and try to run that controller as this user and it flags my assertEquals with `System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: (), Actual: (Account:{Name=test1, RecordTypeId=01280000000EqShAAK, Id=001C000001PibPOIAZ})`.

Test Code:

```
@isTest
public without sharing class Test_Sorted_Account_Controller {

//test method for Sorted Account page controller 
static testMethod void testAccountController(){

    //Create an instance class so that you can call the getAccounts method from the Sorted_Accounts_Filtered_by_User class
    //This copies the Sorted Account controller as a test controller
    Sorted_Account_Filtered_by_User testController= new Sorted_Account_Filtered_by_User();

//Add a sales rep with which to test the filtered accounts controller.
    User testSalesRep = new User(Alias='SRep', email='sales.email@test.com' ,LastName='Testing'
                                            ,EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8'  ,LocaleSidKey='en_US' ,LanguageLocaleKey='en_US' 
                                            ,ProfileID='00e80000000z1QfAAI' ,TimeZoneSidKey='America/los_Angeles' 
                                            ,UserName='Sales.email@test.com' ,isActive=true);

    String lastName = 'Testing';
    User aSalesRep = database.query('Select ID from User where LastName=:lastName');
    //Two accounts with 'Customer' record type...
    Account testAcct1 = new Account(Name='test1' ,recordTypeID='01280000000EqShAAK');
    Account testAcct2 = new Account(Name='test2' ,recordTypeID='01280000000EqShAAK');
    //...And one with 'Other' record type.
    //This is relevant because the controller should only return 'Customer' accounts.
    Account testAcct3 = new Account(Name='test3' ,recordTypeID='012C0000000YNSzIAO');

    //Now let's insert the accounts so that the test class can access them.
        List<Account> testAccts = new List<Account> ();
        testAccts.add(testAcct1);  
        testAccts.add(testAcct2); 
        testAccts.add(testAcct3);
        insert testAccts;
        testAcct1.Owner=aSalesRep;
        update testAcct1;


    //Set up a list of accounts that should appear under the Sales Rep's view
    List<Account> salesAccounts = new List<Account> ();
    salesAccounts.add(testAcct1);
    //And a list that should show up in general view
    List<Account> genAccounts = new List<Account> ();
    genAccounts.add(testAcct2);

    //Start the Sales Rep test
    Test.startTest();
    system.runAs(testSalesRep){
        //This should return the Sales Rep's Accounts (testAcct1 in this case)
        System.assertEquals(testController.getAccounts(),salesAccounts);

    }
}
```

Relevant Controller Code:

```
//First let's identify the current user and their profile (which will be used to determine whether they are a regional sales rep).
    id user_profile = UserInfo.getProfileId();
    id current_user_id = UserInfo.getUserId();
    //Now let's set up numRecords which will be used in the getAccounts() method below
    public integer numRecords{get; set;}
    //pageSize will be referenced by the acctList as well as the visualforce page
    public integer pageSize{get; set;}

    /*The StandardSetController below checks to see if it contains values and runs a query (based on the conditional logic we've defined) if
     *no values are found. 
     */
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController acctList {
        get{
            if (acctList == null) {

                if(user_profile == '00e80000000z1QfAAI') {
                    pageSize=20;
                    acctList = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    //Following is the SOQL query returned for regional sales reps
                                [
                                Select ID, Name, BillingState, BillingCountry, Region__c 
                                from account
                                where OwnerId = :current_user_id 
                                    and Type in ('Customer','Prospect') 
                                Order by BillingState,Name
                                ]));
                    acctList.setPageSize(pageSize);
                    numRecords=acctList.getResultSize();
                }
                Else {
                    pageSize=50;
                    acctList = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                    //Following is the SOQL query run for all users who are not regional sales reps
                                [
                                Select ID, Name, BillingState, BillingCountry, Region__c 
                                from account 
                                Where BillingCountry = 'USA' 
                                    and Type in ('Customer','Prospect') 
                                Order by BillingState, Name
                                ]));
                    acctList.setPageSize(pageSize);
                    numRecords=acctList.getResultSize();
                }
            }
            return acctList;
        }
        set;
    }

    //getAccounts method creates a new list and fills it with all of the records from acctList.  These are then returned later as our result.
    public List<account> getAccounts() {
        List<account> ListOfAccts = new List<account>();
        for(account acct: (list<account>)acctList.getrecords())
            ListOfAccts.add(acct);
        return ListOfAccts;
    }
```

Can you help me figure out why the controller works in production, but in test it won't ID the test sales rep and correctly fulfill the assertEquals requirement?

Comment: Are you running the test in a sandbox where a profile with ID 00e80000000z1QfAAI exists because it is a copy of production?

Comment: No, I'm running it on a live production instance using the Force.com IDE.